# Django: getting form's name

Tags: django

Is it possible to get the name of the form from the request? Possibly I might want to have multiple forms on one page and each of process them differently.

```
<form action="." method="post" name="station_select">
<form action="." method="post" name="bike_select">
```

I'd want to execute some function for the case, when user selects a bike and another when he selects a station.

Comment: Usually people use `id` to identify individual dom elements. Do you think that makes more sense?

Comment: I'm just learning django and I didn't know it. Could you provide me some link with some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The form name is not part of the POST request, and that is a HTTP characteristic, not Django's.

You can include a `hidden` element in each form though:

```
<form action="." method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="station_select" value="">

<form action="." method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="bike_select" value="">
```

And then, in the view:

```
if 'station_select' in request.POST:
    ...
elif 'bike_select' in request.POST:
    ...
```

Or, if you have a different submit button for each, they may also have names (and they could even be in the same form).

```
<input type="submit" name="station_select" value="Go">
<input type="submit" name="bike_select" value="Go">
```